# Navigating to an xhtml document in webbrowser control opens up Chrome

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome

I have written a program which uses webbrowser control for previewing locally stored xhtml documents.

It works fine on my PC and another machine, but when I send it to someone, when he tries to load the document, a Chrome popup shows and asks whether we want to open or save the page. If we press open, then the Chrome window opens and my webbrowser control says that navigation to the webpage was cancelled.

I tried that on two PCs that use chrome (same version as the problematic one) and only the third machine acts strange.

Any idea why does this happen?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out that the version of Internet Explorer matters. 
The problematic PC had 8.0 IE, which would complain about opening xHTML files.
Upgrade to IE 11 solved the problem.

So, the WebBrowser is largely dependant on the browser installed.

Cheers!